# Groovy calls deprecated getter method instead of public class field

Tags: java, groovy, properties

I am using groovy to talk to a Java library. I am trying to get the value of a class field, and I am having trouble because of groovy's implicit call to getters. I'm doing something like this:

```
println model.schemaComponent
```

and groovy is calling the `getSchemaComponent` method.

The problem I have is that the Java class has a `public` field named `schemaComponent`, and a getter method for that field (`getSchemaComponent`). Now, in the Java library, they have deprecated the getter method in favor of the public field, and the getter method always returns `null`.

Is there a way to somehow *force* groovy to get the value from the public field and not the getter method?

Thank you

Comment: I'd run far, far away from that library. Deliberately leaving the method in and breaking the contract is *insane*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy has a [direct field-access operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_direct_field_access_operator) `.@`, so you can write your expression like this:

```
println model.@schemaComponent
```

That said, any library that leaves an API call in place while trashing its semantics is one I would run away from fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yeah, that's what I thought too. It's very weird what they have done, but I don't think I have a choice ..

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`.@` operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_direct_field_access_operator):

```
model.@schemaComponent
```

*[Live example](http://ideone.com/VIyyRI)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The live example was useful too